# Coda Slider and SEO

Tags: seo

I am using a Coda Slider to deliver content on the main page of my site with 5 tabs that scroll.  My question is this -- how is Google going to index this?  Is it going to index it as one big page or because of the hash tags -- will it index it as multiple pages?

Here is my navigation structure:

```
                <ul>
                    <li id="home"><a href="#content-home">Home</a></li>
                    <li id="work"><a href="#work-showcase">Work Showcase</a></li>
                    <li id="offerings"><a href="#brand-offerings">Offerings</a></li>
                    <li id="about"><a href="#about-company">About</a></li>
                    <li id="reason"><a href="#wow-factor">Reason to Believe</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Here's another issue -- if I'm on an internal page that doesn't use the Coda Slider -- to link back to a panel that is part of the Coda Slider -- I have to use this format:

```
  <a href="/#wow-factor">Reason to Believe</a>
```

It goes to the correct slide -- but it leaves the /#wow-factor in the URL.  Examples:

```
  http://209.142.68.153/#wow-factor
```

When sliding through the Coda Slider -- it leaves "#wow-factor" in the URL for every slide.  My main concern is having Google index multiple content . . . thinking that these are duplicate pages for every #hashtag.  The Coda Slider doesn't seem to update the URL line every time it is clicked.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Google will index that as one page as hashbangs don't make a URL different by being there (unlike query strings which do). But if you wanted to be 100% sure you should use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to specify which URL Google should consider as being the version of the page you want displayed in their search results.

Comment: Now, this isn't AJAX page but worth to know about is Googles initiative to AJAX crawlable pages as described here https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Answer (score 0):

technically they are not separate pages, they on the same page so Google will index 1 page